# "He committed a crime two days ago and is a man wanted by the police right now." - ok to connect the two verb phrases like that?

Tags: conjunctions

Coordinating conjunctions are used to connect two words, phrases, and clauses, etc.

Do the parts that are connected have to be the same part of speech (for example, both being nouns, phrases, or clauses...)?

**Example 1:**

> I didn't finish my assignments on time because of **having other things to do on that day** and **my lack of interest in the subject**.

**Having other things to do on that day** is a gerund and **my lack of interest in the subject** is a noun phrase. Are they allowed to be connected this way?

**Example 2:**

> I didn't finish my assignments on time **because I had other things to do on that day** and **because of my lack of interest in the subject**.

**because I had other things to do on that day** is a clause and **because of my lack of interest in the subject** is a prepositional phrase. Are they allowed to be connected this way?

**Example 3:**

> He is an environmentalist and doing volunteer work at the beach right now.

**environmentalist** is a noun and **doing volunteer work** is a verb phrase. Are they allowed to be connected this way?

**Example 4:**

> He committed a crime two days ago and is a man wanted by the police right now.

**committed a crime** and **is a man** are both verb phrases, but they are in different tenses, so are they allowed to be connected this way?

Comment: Example #3 is non-idiomatic. Discard the word ***and***. Personally I'd say the two assertions in #4 would be better connected by ***because*** - phrased as ***Because** he committed a crime two days ago **he is wanted by the police** right now* OR resequenced to *He is wanted by the police right now **because** he committed a crime two days ago*. There's nothing "unusual" about mixing tenses in statements like *He **is** a man who **did** something.*